# VS Code: HTML div class name turns into points (...)

Tags: html, class, visual-studio-code

So I learn literally about HTML CSS and JS and I found something odd in my VS Code.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, whenever I write a class name it'll turn into points and I have to point my cursor in order to see the names which frustrates me. But there's nothing wrong when I wrote an id.

I did re-install VS Code, restarted my PC, and reset to the default setting but it brings nothing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I cannot reproduce on my side. For me the syntax highlighting of the `div` tags looks different, it's in the same blue color as all the other tags. Do you maybe have an extension installed which causes the issue?

Comment: I didn't install any extension. I still have from previous VS Code before I uninstalled and re-installed

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating extensions, even the standard ones.

Start with this one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moalamri.inline-fold

Comment: So I tried what u suggested me and it is still the same.

Comment: Try this one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moalamri.inline-fold